# How to Unban an IP properly with Fail2Ban

Tags: firewall, iptables, fail2ban

I'm using Fail2Ban on a server and I'm wondering how to unban an IP properly.

I know I can work with IPTables directly: `iptables -D fail2ban-ssh <number>`

But is there not a way to do it with the `fail2ban-client`?

In the manuals it states something like: `fail2ban-client get ssh actionunban <IP>`. But that doesn't work.

Also, I don't want to `/etc/init.d/fail2ban restart` as that would lose all the bans in the list.

Comment: I accidentally locked myself out when I was trying to log into my Linode VPS, so now I have to stop Fail2Ban via the web console to log in with PuTTY. I hope the ban is not permanent as I want to continue logging in without having to disable fail2ban.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony one way you can avoid this in the future is to configure your jail to include your IP address in the `ignoreips` value. I've added my two VPN exit points as well as the SPF ranges for Google's network, since the box running fail2ban is a GCP Compute instance. Adding your IP address to that `ignoreips` attribute will allow you to run any nefarious command without banning yourself.

Comment: Note that this question is very old now, and it was using a pre-Systemd system.

Comment: Searchers in **2022**: the accepted answer is no longer up to date, **scroll down to [@kashiraja's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/967506)**

Answer (score 431, accepted):

With Fail2Ban before v0.8.8:

```
fail2ban-client get YOURJAILNAMEHERE actionunban IPADDRESSHERE
```

With Fail2Ban v0.8.8 and later:

```
fail2ban-client set YOURJAILNAMEHERE unbanip IPADDRESSHERE
```

The hard part is finding the right jail:

1. Use `iptables -L -n` to find the rule name...
2. ...then use `fail2ban-client status | grep "Jail list" | sed -E 's/^[^:]+:[ \t]+//' | sed 's/,//g'` to get the actual jail names.  The rule name and jail name may not be the same but it should be clear which one is related to which.

Comment: If you have the following error `'Invalid Action name'`, read [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/475117/125960)

Comment: With recent versions of `fail2ban` you should be using `fail2ban-client set JAIL_NAME unbanip 1.2.3.4`.

Comment: What is the default jail name? `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can find jail name in fail2ban log if you look for your IP

Comment: sshd was the jail name for me.

Comment: One tip: If you see chains called `fail2ban-xyz`, your jail name is `xyz`. Therefore, the command to run is `fail2ban-client set xyz unbanip <ip>`. (Tested this on Debian 8.6)

Comment: Can't we just edit a file and remove a line somewhere (+ a reload)? It would be more easy this way (at least for me).

Comment: Use `sudo iptables -L -n | less` to avoid long DNS lookups.. and get a quick scroll-able/searchable list.

Comment: Usefull command for displaying all bans `sudo fail2ban-client status | grep "Jail list:" | sed "s/ //g" | awk '{split($2,a,",");for(i in a) system("sudo fail2ban-client status " a[i])}' | grep "Status\|IP list"` from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/893108/423684) .. slightly modified it (added two `sudo`s)  for a normal user using sudo.

Comment: Centos 7. `cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep IP#` there you have Jail Name.  f2b 0.9+

Comment: In the latest versions of fail2ban you do not need the jail name: `fail2ban-client unban <address>` works

Comment: You can also use `sudo fail2ban-client unban <ip>` to unban from all jails

Comment: If it's someone you wish to whitelist anyway, you can add them under `ignoreip` directive in jail.local. When you restart the service, it will also remove any IP bans found on anything under ignoreip.

Comment: even though it's been long since this question has been asked & this answer has been answered, just to add you can `sudo fail2ban-client banned` to get the list of jails along with the banned IPs.

Answer (score 101):

Since v0.8.8 there is the `unbanip` option (`actionunban` isn't for this purpose)
It can be triggered by the `set` command, if you look at the list of options, you will see the syntax is.
So it will be (by heart, please check):

```
fail2ban-client set ssh-iptables unbanip IPADDRESSHERE
```

more generic:

```
fail2ban-client set JAILNAMEHERE unbanip IPADDRESSHERE
```

works for me

Comment: The unbanip command was added in version 0.8.8. The best solution if you are running 0.8.8 or later.

Comment: The issue related to this in fail2ban tracker is this:  https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/132

Comment: this is the correct answer for current versions.  thank you!

Comment: getting "Invalid command (no set action or not yet implemented)"

Comment: you need to state the correct jailname (for example sshd or sshd-dos, see your fail2ban log)

Answer (score 95):

Example for SSH in interactive mode.

type in bash:

```
fail2ban-client -i
```

then in interactive mode type read the status of a jail:

```
status sshd
```

you'll get:

```
Status for the jail: ssh
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 6
|  `- File list:    /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned: 2
   `- Banned IP list:   203.113.167.162
```

then type in fail2ban interactive mode:

```
set sshd unbanip 203.113.167.162
```

you'll get:

```
203.113.167.162
```

it means no longer `203.113.167.162` in ban list.

Comment: For me the jail name was `sshd` (Ubuntu 16)

Comment: On mine, it says total banned: 6, but the list under banned ip is just empty :( have to trail through logs

Comment: The answer is not coherent with the provided example. The `set sshd` can't work if the jail is called `ssh` without trailing `d` AFAIK.

Comment: Perfect! After 2 hours of searching and head-bashing, finally an answer that works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 21):

The answer of ukoda is wrong:

Call `fail2ban-client` without parameters and you see a list of possible commands:

```
get JAIL actionunban ACT
```

This gets the unban command for the action ACT for JAIL.

Look into the action parameter of the jail you defined, you probably have an iptables action and maybe some more like sendmail, whois or whatever. so in case your action was iptables it will look like this:

```
fail2ban-client get JAIL actionunban iptables
```

and the answer will be:

```
iptables -D fail2ban-NAME -s IP -j DROP
```

It will only show you what you would have to write for an unban. There is no unban command itself.

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me, to unban from SSH jail `iptables -D fail2ban-ssh -s <IP> -j DROP`. Thanks ingo!

Answer (score 11):

If you are running version [v0.10.2](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/fail2ban/fail2ban-client.1.en.html):

> sudo fail2ban-client unban YOUR_IP_ADDRESS

This is from help:

> `unban <IP> ... <IP>                 unbans <IP> (in all jails and database)`

Confirmed to work in my case when I most likely got banned due to ssh client logging in repeatedly with wrong password.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer

Answer (score 10):

If 192.168.2.1 is banned

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Check which Chain it's banned in e.g.

> Chain fail2ban-sasl (1 references)
>
> DROP       all  --  192.168.2.1  anywhere

Then:

```
# to view the proper command for un-banning
sudo fail2ban-client get sasl actionunban
# actual command
iptables -D fail2ban-sasl -s 192.168.2.1 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 4):

You first need to get the name of the jail. You can get the list (in most cases it will be only ssh jail):

```
fail2ban-client status
```

After getting the jail name you can check which IPs are being ignored.

```
fail2ban-client get ssh ignoreip
```

If your IP is in ignore list, you can delete it via:

```
fail2ban-client set ssh delignoreip your_ip_address
vi /etc/hosts.deny
```

Remove your host entry:

```
fail2ban-client reload
```

Comment: The ignore list is a list of IPs to never ban. That's totally unrelated to the list of currently banned IPs, which is the list that OP wants to remove an IP from.

Answer (score 3):

Using fail2ban v.0.8.6:

```
$ sudo fail2ban-client status # to reveal your JAIL name (mine is ssh)
$ sudo fail2ban-client set ssh delignoreip your_ip_address
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts.deny # delete your ip address
$ sudo fail2ban-client reload
```

Comment: This assumes that hosts.deny was the action used.... But it is still more useful than things that try to change the method of unbanning IPs on the older versions by using `actionunban`...

Comment: The `delignoreip` action is **not** removing an IP from a ban, it is removing an IP from the list of ignored IP (i.e. IP that will never get banned).

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately with version 0.8.2 of fail2ban-client the command:

```
fail2ban-client get jail actionunban ipaddress
```

does not run. To solve the problem, best choice is upgrade fail2ban to latest version and use new option:

```
unbanip
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip ip_here
```

would work.

Answer (score 2):

From version 0.8.8 this could be a handy script for you - could easily be tweaked to unban from all jails.

I just call it "`getf2bstatus.sh`"

Example usage `./getf2bstatus.sh 1.2.3.4`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Jails where $1 is locked up:"
JAILS=`fail2ban-client status | grep "Jail list" | sed -E 's/^[^:]+:[ \t]+//' | sed 's/,//g'`
for JAIL in $JAILS
do
  currentjail=`fail2ban-client status $JAIL | grep -B 8 $1 | grep Status | awk '{printf $5}'`
  if [[ ${#currentjail} -gt a ]] ; then
        echo $currentjail
  fi
done
echo
echo "To unban $1 use the following commands:"
for JAIL in $JAILS
do
  currentjail=`fail2ban-client status $JAIL | grep -B 8 $1 | grep Status | awk '{printf $5}'`
  if [[ ${#currentjail} -gt a ]] ; then
        echo "fail2ban-client set $currentjail unbanip $1"
   fi
done
```

Output?

```
Jails where 1.2.3.4 is locked up:
ssh

To unban 1.2.3.4 use the following commands:
fail2ban-client set ssh unbanip 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: thanks, crazy that this is not a native feature

Answer (score 2):

Simplest possible way for all jails is like this:

```
fail2ban-client unban 10.20.30.40
```

It will return an integer:

```
0 = ip was not banned (no action was performed)
1 = ip was cleared from the ban list (if ip was in more than 1 jail this number will increase)
```

Good idea is to add ip to ignore list (no restart required) so that you will not run into this problem again:

```
fail2ban-client set JAILNAME addignoreip 10.20.30.40
```

When done working on this ip:

```
fail2ban-client set JAILNAME delignoreip 10.20.30.40
```

Answer (score 1):

If an IP is in multiple jails this becomes a pain.

one-liner to remove 192.168.1.2 from all jails:

```
 for jail in $(fail2ban-client status | grep 'Jail list:' | sed 's/.*Jail list://' | sed 's/,//g'); do fail2ban-client set $jail unbanip 192.168.1.2; done
```

a script to do the same
https://gist.github.com/yolabingo/c810db6fe7f8bfcb9eb4f6ffc531e474

Answer (score 1):

You can use my simply script :D

```
echo "Display all service"
#Edit and Add/Del your service
sudo fail2ban-client status phpmyadmin-syslog
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-fakegooglebot
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-noscript
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-overflows
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-auth
sudo fail2ban-client status  apache-badbots
sudo fail2ban-client status  mysqld-auth
sudo fail2ban-client status  proftpd
sudo fail2ban-client status  sshd
echo "Choose service to unban"
read service
echo "Status of Service"
sudo fail2ban-client status $service
echo "Enter ip to be unban"
read ip
sudo fail2ban-client set $service unbanip $ip
echo "Status of service after unban"
sudo fail2ban-client status $service
```

Save and enter 'sh yourfilename.sh'

Optional, if you want received resultat by mail you can use this :)

````
#Empty file log
echo "" > /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
#Add Date to log
date >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log

#Add status service on log
sudo fail2ban-client status phpmyadmin-syslog >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-fakegooglebot >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-noscript >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-overflows >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status apache-auth >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status  apache-badbots >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status  mysqld-auth >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status  proftpd >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log
sudo fail2ban-client status  sshd >> /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log

#Send mail 
mutt -b "yourname@gmail.com" -s "Sujet: Log Fail2Ban" < /home/pi/Scripts/log/ban.log ```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about removing the ban from a specific jail, the current incarnation of Fail2Ban allows a very simple command:

fail2ban-client unban IPADDRESS

This will remove the IP from all jails. Super easy!

Answer (score 0):

I find the fail by doing
`grep 10.20.30.40 /var/log/fail2ban.log`

which gives an output like

```
2021-08-23 10:09:17,394 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [ssh] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:17
2021-08-23 10:09:17,395 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [sshd] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:17
2021-08-23 10:09:20,936 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [sshd] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:20
2021-08-23 10:09:20,940 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [ssh] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:20
2021-08-23 10:09:22,654 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [ssh] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:22
2021-08-23 10:09:22,655 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [sshd] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:22
2021-08-23 10:09:22,917 fail2ban.actions        [581]: NOTICE  [ssh] Ban 10.20.30.40
2021-08-23 10:09:23,085 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [recidive] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:22
2021-08-23 10:09:23,384 fail2ban.actions        [581]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 10.20.30.40
2021-08-23 10:09:24,084 fail2ban.actions        [581]: NOTICE  [recidive] Ban 10.20.30.40
2021-08-23 10:09:24,099 fail2ban.filter         [581]: INFO    [recidive] Found 10.20.30.40 - 2021-08-23 10:09:23
```

From this I can see that I have to unban the IP from three jails:
`fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip 10.20.30.40`
`fail2ban-client set ssh unbanip 10.20.30.40`
`fail2ban-client set recidive unbanip 10.20.30.40`

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to find the IP first, you can do `sudo fail2ban-client banned`. This will show you the list of jails as well as the IPs inside them. Then you can either do `sudo fail2ban-client unban <IP>` or `sudo fail2ban-client set <JAIL> unbanip <IP>`.

Comment: you have to think about a question and Software which is 13 years old. previously it was not such easy ;) but the author of fail2ban is jumping here around and may correct me if I been wrong