# Unban everyone from a specific jail

Tags: fail2ban

I'm testing a jail configuration, and sometimes I need to release falsely banned IPs from that jail. So not a [specific IP](https://serverfault.com/a/336001), not [everyone from all jails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286133), but everyone from a given jail.

- Closest I could find is [`get JAIL actionunban ACT`](https://serverfault.com/a/349669), which requires me to specify an action, and feels like it's meant to be used for something else (also, what if I have multiple actions?).
- The docs [mention the `stop` command](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Commands#JAIL_CONTROL):

  > stop <JAIL>       stops the jail <JAIL>. The jail is removed

  - But I'm not sure if it will remove the jail completely?
  - Plus it says nothing about unbanning the IPs.
  - And I don't really need to stop the jail, I need it running. If I run `start <JAIL>` right away, will it restore the bans?
- Some people also mention manually clearing the iptables rules, but that doesn't feel like the right way to handle this.

All I need is to reset the jail, i.e. **release everyone from the jail as if they were never banned**, and immediately move on. Feel like this should be easy, but googling since yesterday, and can't find an exact answer. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I'm not sure if it will remove the jail completely?
>   If I run start  right away, will it restore the bans?

Yes and yes.
It will remove jail, so you need to start it again (use `restart` instead)...
but a start will cause a restore for the active bans.
Newest version (>= 0.10) had an option `--unban` for that purposes.
In older versions you've to remove tickets from database for the jail before you'd start it.
Or unban the IPs with individually.

> Plus it says nothing about unbanning the IPs.

Then maybe you've indeed an older version:

```
fail2ban-client --help; # excerpt with operations doing unban:
Fail2Ban v0.10.5
    restart [--unban] [--if-exists] <JAIL>
    reload [--restart] [--unban] [--if-exists] <JAIL>
    unban --all
    unban <IP> ... <IP>
    set <JAIL> unbanip [--report-absent] <IP> ... <IP>
```

See https://manpages.debian.org/buster/fail2ban/fail2ban-client.1.en.html for manual of 0.10.

Comment: Thank you, I'm on v0.10.2, so `fail2ban-client reload --unban <JAIL>` worked perfectly!